# Continue bulleted numbering from previous slide

Tags: vba, powerpoint

I'm trying to write a routine to enable me to continue numbering including style from the previous slide.  I got half way there and got stuck.

First thing is I'm always getting the same bullet.type regardless of the style that is applied on the previous slide.

Secondly, I can't figure out to identify the last numbered line and its bullet style on the previous slide.  I wrote some pseudocode and left it at that as I tried to get working but was stuck at the previous post.  I would need help on how to test if a line is bulleted and what type of bullet and style it is.

Code follows.

Thanks in advance.

```
Sub ContinueNumbering()
Dim oSlide As slide
Dim oShape As Shape
Dim PreviousBulletType As Long
Dim i As Single

'on err goto err_handler
If ActiveWindow.Selection.Type = ppSelectionNone Then GoTo err_handler
If ActiveWindow.Selection.ShapeRange.Count <> 1 Then GoTo err_handler

Set oShape = ActiveWindow.Selection.ShapeRange(1)
Set oSlide = Application.ActiveWindow.View.slide

If oSlide.SlideIndex = 1 Then
   MsgBox "No previous slide.", vbCritical, "Error"
   Exit Sub
End If

With ActivePresentation.Slides(oSlide.SlideIndex - 1).Shapes(oShape.Name)
   With .textFrame.textRange.ParagraphFormat
      PreviousBulletType = .bullet.Type
      MsgBox .bullet.Type
   End With
End With


'' //////////////////////////////////////
'' Pseudo code from here on
''///////////////////////////////////////

'' For...next lines in previous slide
'' test if bulleted or numbered
'' if first line with bullet found is numbered
'' count the number of numbers
'' style to apply = bullet style of last shape on previous slide
''
'' apply bullet style to selected shape, textbox or placeholder
''

With ActiveWindow.Selection.ShapeRange(1)

    With .textFrame.textRange.ParagraphFormat.bullet

        .Type = ppBulletNumbered

        .StartValue = UserInput
        
      End With
   End With


Exit Sub

err_handler:
MsgBox "Please select a single shape.", vbCritical, "Error"
On Error Resume Next

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code you were using was giving as result the number of the first item in the bullet list, I amended as per below to count the paragraphs (i.e. in this case the lines) and continue the numbered list to the selected shape.
I tested it and it works unless you add text after the previous bulleted list (that is, if at the end of the list there is not a numbered list item, it will not work). Also, there should not be empty bullet number lines in the previous list or they will be counted as well.

```
Sub ContinueNumbering()
Dim oSlide As slide
Dim oShape As Shape
Dim PreviousBulletType As Long
Dim i As Integer
Dim ppSelectionTextRange As TextRange


Dim bulletNum As Long

'on err goto err_handler
If ActiveWindow.Selection.Type = ppSelectionNone Then GoTo err_handler
If ActiveWindow.Selection.ShapeRange.Count <> 1 Then GoTo err_handler

Set oShape = ActiveWindow.Selection.ShapeRange(1)
Set oSlide = Application.ActiveWindow.View.slide

If oSlide.SlideIndex = 1 Then
   MsgBox "No previous slide.", vbCritical, "Error"
   Exit Sub
End If

    With ActivePresentation.Slides(oSlide.SlideIndex - 1).Shapes(oShape.Name)
    
         For i = 1 To .TextFrame.TextRange.Paragraphs.Count 'here the number of lines is counted
              i = .TextFrame.TextRange.Paragraphs.Count
         Next i
    
         With .TextFrame.TextRange.Paragraphs(i)
             bulletNum = .ParagraphFormat.Bullet.Number 'here the bullet number is found
         End With
    End With



    With ActiveWindow.Selection.ShapeRange(1)
    
        With .TextFrame.TextRange.ParagraphFormat.Bullet
    
            .Type = ppBulletNumbered
    
            .StartValue = bulletNum + 1  'here the numbering is continued
            
          End With
    End With


Exit Sub

err_handler:
MsgBox "Please select a single shape.", vbCritical, "Error"
On Error Resume Next

End Sub
```